# what does my html not render on the page?

Tags: html, html-rendering

I have this page at

http://kornar.co.uk/example.html

But it doesnt render HTML. I know its there because when I check `view source` the HTML code is there, on my localhost it works perfectly, thanks for your help!!

Comment: Works for me—have you fixed it since asking? Often the cause for a completely missing page is an unclosed `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to start, js/jquery.js is missing so none of your js is going to run...  all the tabs are hidden so without the js the code in the tabs won't be come visible...

Comment: thanks for the answer, im offcially the stupidest html coder on the planet, im so soryy for a silly question i completely missed it! thanks again!!

Comment: It's loaded now because he fixed it =]

Answer (score 2):

Its works correctly for me.
There is possibily two explanation why it do not works for you :
- Your Browser cache need to be cleared
- Your DNS cache need to be cleared.

Try both and let us now if it works

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i think it was what @superfro said about a missing jquery file, so stupid lol! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Line 90 in your layout.css file says:

```
.tab {
    padding: 16px;
    display: none;
}
```

If you remove the "display:none" bit, you'll see more.
Try to use Firebug when debugging stuff like this, it's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You have .colorpicker set to display:none in the css file.